# Submit form with link inside php

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to submit the form as a link instead of a button inside php and it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? It works outside the php code but not inside.

```
<nav class="nav-right">
      <ul>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
          echo
          '<form id="logoutfrm" action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" onclick="document.forms["logoutfrm"].submit();">Logout</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          </form>';
        } else {
          echo
          '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="signup.php">Sign-Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>';
        }
        ?>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is not a PHP question. Include the relevant HTML, not server-side code.

Comment: And you're going to have problems with your quotes inside the attribute. You should be using proper event binding instead of `onclick` attributes.

Comment: This is where the problem is I don't understand how I asked the question wrong? I don't want to post pages of HTML.

Comment: You don't need to post pages of HTML. Just the stuff that's relevant. For example, the HTML generated by the PHP code you currently have in your question should be 9 lines long.

Comment: Maybe I am confused miken but it is just simply not running the php file. Thanks for your replies. I just wanted to know if it was possible to run a script of a onclick since I am using a link...

Answer (score -1):

Just fixed it by escaping the "" with \'

Answer (score -2):

```
<nav class="nav-right">
  <ul>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
      echo
      '<form id="logoutfrm" action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="post">
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('logoutfrm').submit();">Logout</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </form>';
    } else {
      echo
      '<li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="signup.php">Sign-Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>';
    }
    ?>
  </ul>
```

test : https://jsfiddle.net/0whfsc3a/